# What does it mean when elements have 'positive weights'?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to do an exercise question and the first part of the description is confusing me. It says :

**For n distinct elements x_1...x_n with positive weight w_1...w_n such that the summation of all of the weight is 1...**

I have tried Wikipedia, but I still don't understand what it means by "weights". Can someone give me an example so I can understand? I'm not sure if weight is referring to the actual elements value or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ are the weights; they are positive numbers such that $w_1+\ldots+w_n=1$. For $i=1,\ldots,n$, $w_i$ is the weight assigned to the value $x_i$. Typically we’re looking at something like

$$w_1x_1+w_2x_2+\ldots+w_nx_n\;,\tag{1}$$

which is called a *weighted sum* of the numbers $x_i$. If $w_i=\frac1n$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, $(1)$ becomes simply

$$\frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n}n\;,$$

the ordinary arithmetic mean of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and we’re giving each of the numbers $x_i$ the same importance (weight) in determining the average. Essentially the weight $w_i$ is the fraction of the influence that you want the value $x_i$ to have on the weighted sum. If you want some of the variables to have greater influence than others, you arrange this by giving them larger weights.

Suppose, for instance, that $n=3$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are scores (out of $100$) on midterm exams, and $x_3$ is the score (also out of $100$) on the final exam. We might want to make the final count twice as heavily towards the overall grade as each of the midterms. In that case we could let $w_1=w_2=\frac14$ and $w_3=\frac12$; since the weights sum to $1$, the maximum possible total is $100$, but instead of giving us the ordinary average of the three exam scores, the weighted sum $\frac14x_1+\frac14x_2+\frac12x_3$ gives us a score that counts the final twice as heavily as either midterm.